# SSIS and ETL speed

Tags: ssis, etl

I read plenty of articles stataing that SSIS and ETL are much faster and more efficient than using VB6 recordsets and VB.NET DataReaders, however I do not fully understand why this is the case.

I created an SSIS package that looped through one million records and created a new table and did the same in VB and this confirmed that SSIS is very fast.

I understand that all the processing is done in the data tier so there are no costly trips from the application server to the database server, but is there an MSDN article that expalins the algorithm that makes SSIS a lot quicker?

I have a VB6 app that is very slow and think SSIS is the solution.

Comment: SSIS is obviously optimised for ETL work as it's specifically designed to do just that. There is plenty of info on the internet on this, google is your friend.

Comment: You might want to consider that SSIS is optimized for ETL, but VB6 is optimized for the 20th Century.

Comment: John, I did state VB6 and VB.NET in my question.  I realise that VB6 is legacy.

Comment: "legacy" is as much of an understatement as to be nearly false. I can't imagine why you think it's valid to include decade-old software in a performance comparison.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pipeline architecture of the SSIS Data Flow Task is faster due mainly to buffering. By selecting the data in "chunks", the pipeline can perform many operations in RAM, then pass the data buffer downstream for further processing. Depending on the size and shape of the data, and the location and type of the source and destination, you can sometimes achieve better results outside of SSIS.

Comment: Andy, good answer, and hope to see you here more often, but FYI, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Comment: Thanks John, did my answer violate one of the rules listed?

Comment: Yes, you included a signature.

Comment: I will do that from time to time. If it's an issue, I have a solution. :{>